# Unary operator expected in shell script

Tags: bash, visual-studio, shell

I am not sure why my code below generates this error `(standard_in) 1: syntax error -bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected` . Can someone please help me figure out the problem here? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash    
BAMLINES=4.47264e+09
FQ1LINES=4000000
FQ2LINES=4000000
DEBUG=1

if [ ! -z ${DEBUG} ]; then
echo "${BAMLINES} lines in .bam"
echo "${FQ1LINES} lines in all ${FQ_OUT1} files"
echo "${FQ2LINES} lines in all ${FQ_OUT2} files"

if [ $(echo "scale=2;${FQ1LINES}/${BAMLINES} > 0.40" | bc) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Warning, FQ1 file contains ${FQ1LINES} lines - less than 40% of the number of reads of .bam file"
  fi
if [ $(echo "scale=2;${FQ2LINES}/${BAMLINES} > 0.4" | bc) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Warning, FQ2 file contains ${FQ2LINES} lines - less than 40% of the number of reads of .bam file"
  fi  
fi
```

Comment: Use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`

Comment: @anubhava Now it gives `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash`?

Comment: @anubhava Yes I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
$ echo "scale=2;($FQ1LINES/$BAMLINES) > 0.40"
scale=2;(4000000/) > 0.40
# ..............^^
```

You want to use either `BAMLINE` or `BAMLINES` but not both.

---

```sh
$ echo "scale=2;($FQ1LINES/$BAMLINES) > 0.40" | bc
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

Because of that error, the output of `$(echo ... | bc)` is empty, and then `[` only gets 2 arguments. When `[` gets 2 arguments, the first operator is expected to be a unary operator (like `-z` is) -- `-eq` is not a unary operator.

---

You need to quote any variables/command expansions within `[...]`. In this case you'd get a different but more meaningful error:

```sh
$ [ "$(echo "scale=2;${FQ1LINES}/${BAMLINES} > 0.40" | bc)" -eq 0 ]
(standard_in) 1: parse error
bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

Or use `[[...]]` and you'll just see the bc error

```sh
$ [[ $(echo "scale=2;${FQ1LINES}/${BAMLINES} > 0.40" | bc) -eq 0 ]]
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```